# Instagram/Facebook client OAuth2 Unavailable app

Tags: facebook-login, instagram-graph-api

i'am building a Flask App that retrieve comment from Instagram Live. I have some problem setting up the Client OAuth 2.0.

The aim is to allow user to easily connect with there Instagram account so they can save comments from Live media.

For now I have try several things.

Firt, here is a code snippet :

```
import os
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'KEY.ngrok-free.app'
app.config['PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME'] = 'https'
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1)

# Set up OAuth2 URLs
authorization_base_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"

# Set up OAuth2 client_id and client_secret
client_id = "ID"
client_secret = "SECRET"

@app.route("/login/instagram")
def login_instagram():
    # Set up the OAuth2 session
    instagram = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=url_for("instagram_callback", _external=True), scope=["public_profile"])

    # Get the authorization URL
    authorization_url, state = instagram.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
    print("State:", state)
    print("Authorization URL:", authorization_url)
    
    # Print the generated redirect_uri
    generated_redirect_uri = url_for("instagram_callback", _external=True)
    print("Generated redirect URI:", generated_redirect_uri)

    # Save the state in the user's session
    session["oauth_state"] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route("/instagram/callback")
def instagram_callback():
    # Get the authorization code from the request
    code = request.args.get("code")

    # Set up the OAuth2 session
    instagram = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=url_for("instagram_callback", _external=True), state=session["oauth_state"])

    try:
        token = instagram.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, code=code)
        print("Received token:", token)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error fetching token:", e)

    # Save the access token in the user's session or database
    session["instagram_access_token"] = token["access_token"]

    return redirect(url_for("dashboard2"))
```

Also, I used ngrok because the localhost is not accepted with http and I didn't wanted to go for SSL.

once I logged to my dev account, it says that, the app is unavailable. I'am the admin of that same app so I should not face this issue unless I got something wrong.

Also, I verified so many times that the redirect URI was the same.

Any ideas?